# Flutter Build Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Was working fine just before and after rebuilding the process was interrupted with a sudden restart, and after that this is the error showing up, I've tried every possible solution found on the internet.

I run v1.22.6 for the project.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0, 16.0.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.7
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:15.0.1
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Run Flutter Doctor, and check if it gives error related to android licenses? If yes than run flutter doctor --android-licenses. Just accept all and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer, but that's not the cause of the error, everything is fine with flutter doctor. This has happened before, it generally happens when the app build in debug mode is interrupted. Then no solution works, I have to either reinstall the whole OS or leave the laptop unused for 12+ hours. I feel like it has to do something with cache. But still it needs a concrete solution. I hope someone could help with this.

Comment: Yup, someone might!

Comment: try deleting the cache file

Comment: I had exactly the same problem today with the same version.. I m tryng everything.. I reinstalled VS, Flutter.. and nothing.  Did you can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dependency versions in **pubspec.yaml** file that you recently added.
Then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

`***.bintray.com` `40X error` is related to jFrog stop update the services in original domain.

```sh
repositories {
  jcenter() // <-- remove this line
  mavenCentral() // <-- add this line
}
```